# Getting ambiguous result using JDBC Metadata API for Hive

Tags: jdbc, hive, database-metadata

I am trying to get Table names for hive using `DatabaseMetaData` in a similar way like RDBMS.

Sample code:

```
try (Connection con = getJdbcConnection(connectionUri, driverName, username, password);) {
        DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(null, null, tableName, null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
       }

  } catch (SQLException e) {
  }

private static void registerDriver(String driverName) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.error("No class found for " + driverName + ". Details: " + e);
        }
    }

private static Connection getJdbcConnection(String connectionUri, String driverName, String username,
        String password) throws SQLException{
    registerDriver(driverName);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, username,password);
}
```

There is no table in a particular database. Using different different table names, I am getting different output.

For example:

I put table name `emp`, there are 3 records with name `emp`

I put table name `employee`, there are 5 records with name `employee`

I put table name `emp12`, it is returning no records *(which is expected)*

---

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Shouldn't I use `DatabaseMetaData` for checking table existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to pass schema name in `getTables` method

Signature:

```
ResultSet getTables(String catalog,
                  String schemaPattern,
                  String tableNamePattern,
                  String[] types)
                    throws SQLException
```

I passed following agruments:

- catalog = null;
- schemaPattern = Hive schema Name
- tableNamePattern = Hive Table Name
- types =  `new String[] { "TABLE" }`

Sample code:

```
    try (Connection con = getJdbcConnection(connectionUri, driverName, username, password);) {
        DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(null, schemaName, tableName, new String[] { "TABLE" });

        while (rs.next()) {
            String tName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            if (tName != null && tName.equals(tableName)) {
                LOG.info("Table [" + tableName + "] is present in the Database.");
                return true;
            }
        }
        rs.close();

        LOG.info("Table [" + tableName + "] is not present in the Database.");
        return false;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error("Not able to get Table Metadata . Caused By: " + e);
    }
```